# Call RestAPI in AppService from DataFactory

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice

Am running a restapi using Azure AppService.
This restApi needs to be called by a Webhook / Web-Activity in Azure DataFactory:

[image]

Currently, am getting this errors:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get?view=rest-appservice-2023-01-01&tabs=HTTP do you want to call this rest api's?

Comment: Hi @PratikLad,

no, i want to call my self-implemented restAPIs, that are running in my docker container - hosted in AppService

Comment: Did you grant the data factory identity permission on your app service app registration ? Also you need to get a token for your application not for management.azure.com